# Can I speedup this mysql query?

Tags: mysql, performance, subquery, query-optimization

part of query is:

```
SELECT * FROM `o` WHERE ....
AND `id` IN     (SELECT DISTINCT `id` FROM `o` WHERE `activity` = '1' AND `date` < '20130310'                      ORDER BY `id` ASC)
AND `id` NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT `id` FROM `o` WHERE `activity` = '1' AND `date` BETWEEN '20130310' AND '20130329' ORDER BY `id` ASC)
....
```

**Desc**: IDs that Before **20130310** have activity and Between 20130310 AND 20130329 doesnt have activity

1) Can I speedup this mysql query?

2) Does help `ORDER BY` to inscrease speed of `IN` and `NOT IN` ?

Comment: no need to use order by command

Comment: @Ankit do you have references for this?

Comment: why do you need an reference for this order by is a command for sorting the selected records and when you are using it in subquery then there is no need to sort the selected record.You can try it yourself by removing it and you will see no changes in your query result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As IN() subqueries are generally slow in MySQL (at leasr before 5.6), you better use join

```
SELECT * FROM `o`
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT `id` AS `idactive` FROM `o` WHERE `activity` = '1' AND `date` BETWEEN '20130310' AND '20130329') as t
USING `id`
WHERE `activity` = '1' AND `date` < '20130310' AND `idactive` IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like that

```
  SELECT * FROM `o` WHERE ....
  AND `id` IN     (SELECT DISTINCT `id` FROM `o` 
                   WHERE `activity` = '1' AND `date` < '20130310'   
                   ORDER BY `id` ASC)
```

you dont need the second AND because you already choosed `date < 20130310` so it will not select `20130311` `20130312` ...`20130329`

**or** you can simply do this query

```
    SELECT * FROM `o` WHERE ....
    AND `activity` = '1' AND `date` < '20130310'   
    GROUP BY `id` 
    ORDER BY `id` ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

If `id` is your primary key (as it should be), one of your two date-related clauses is useless (`` `date` < '20130310' `` always implies `` NOT (`date` BETWEEN '20130310' AND '20130329') ``, allowing you to simplify the thing to:

```
select *
from o
where activity = 1
and date < '20130310'
```

In the event `id` is actually one among other fields (it's a terribly confusing choice for a name, in that case) that is referencing a separate table in a 1-n or n-m relationship, I assume you're looking for ids where at least one has activity in the date range, but no new activity since. In this case, your query can be simplified to:

```
SELECT * FROM `o` WHERE ....
AND `id` IN     (SELECT `id` FROM `o` WHERE `activity` = '1' AND `date` < '20130310')
AND `id` NOT IN (SELECT `id` FROM `o` WHERE `activity` = '1' AND `date` BETWEEN '20130310' AND '20130329')
```

Put another way, the `distinct` and the `order by` clauses are both pointless.

In either case, if relevant, also note that your `date` field should be of type `date`, rather than of type `varchar`.